How does measure theory deal with higher cardinalities?
The second part of the definition of a sigma-algebra is that countable unions of measurable sets are measurable. The second property of a measure is that the measure of countable unions of measurable set is the countable sum of the measures of the disjoint sets.
However, in higher cardinalities, "almost everything" is uncountable. Thus, if we were to define a measure, taking the uncountable union of sets would be ambiguous, because we don't know what "cardinality of union" we are dealing with. We could be taking the union of Aleph-3 sets in Aleph-5 environment, but what does that mean? How is the final measure calculated from the measures of each of the Aleph-3 sets?
In brief, I want to know what are meaningful definitions of measures on sets of higher cardinality, given the basic definition of measures in measure theory.

For measure theory, only countable unions are used, as you said.  For something different, you may want to look up "measurable cardinal".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal  [but that is irrelevant for the "measure-theory" tag.]

It really doesn't make sense to take uncountable sums - you can only really do it if countably many are non-zero. Even in $\mathbb R,$ most things are uncountable.

The notion of infinite sum of an arbitrary set of nonnegative reals that’s used is the supremum of sums over finite subsets. (But this is always infinite if uncountably many are nonzero).

Sure, but the value is $+\infty$ if uncountably many are non-zero. @spaceisdarkgreen
